# How to integrate trac into a nginx/gunicorn/django website?

Tags: nginx, trac

I have a django website, which is setup using NGINX and gunicorn.

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target
[Service]
User=*****
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=*****/mysite
ExecStart=gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
mysite.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    server_name ******;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root *****/mysite;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root *****/mysite/static;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I have installed [trac](https://trac.edgewall.org) a while ago as a standalone process:

```
tracd -s --port 8765 --basic-auth=\
"my_trac,*****/trac/.htpasswd,My Env" *****/trac/my_trac/
```

I would like to add trac to my nginx/gunicorn/django setup, so that I could access it via: `https://example.com/trac` instead of `http://example.com:8765`

Can I get some help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another `location` proxy:

```
location /trac {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8765;
}
```

[You can read more about Nginx proxying here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).